# How to test if Type derives from an abstract base generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, types

Hey I have an abstract generic type `BList<TElement> where TElement : Career`.  Career is abstract type too.

Given a type T, how do I test if it is a BList type? And how can I cast to the base class? I tried `(BList<Career>)object` but the compiler was upset. Apparently I can't write `BList<Career>` because Career is abstract.

Comment: You should be able to use the `is` operator

Comment: Show your code. “compiler was upset” won't tell us much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a bit of ambiguity with your question, so I'll attempt to answer some of the things i think you may be asking...

If you want to check if an instance `T` is a BList you can just use `is`:

```
if (someInstance is BList<Career>)
{
...
}
```

If you want to see if a generic type parameter is a `BList<Career>` you can use `typeof`:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(BList<Career>)
{
...
}
```

But, if you are just wanting to see if it's *any* `BList<>`, you can use reflection:

```
var t = typeof(T);  // or someInstance.GetType() if you have an instance

if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BList<>))
{
    ...
}
```

Now, as far as how do you cast a `BList<TElement>` to a `BList<Career>`?  You can't safely.

This has nothing to do with `Career` being abstract, it has to do with the fact that `BList<Career>` does *not* inherit from `BList<TElement>` even though `Career` inherits from `TElement`.

Consider this:

```
public class Animal { }

public class Dog : Animal { }

public class Cat : Animal { }
```

Given those, ask yoruself why does this not work:

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Cat>();
```

See the problem?  If we allow you to cast a `List<Cat>` to a `List<Animal>`, then all of the sudden the `Add()` method will support `Animal` instead of `Cat`, which means you could do this:

```
animals.Add(new Dog());
```

Clearly, there is no way we should be able to add a `Dog` to a `List<Cat>`.  This is why you can't use a `List<Cat>` as a `List<Animal>` even though `Cat` inherits from `Animal`.

Similar case here.

Comment: Thanks I was all flavours of confused when I tried to ask my question. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
var item = theObject as BList<Career>;
```

If it's `null` then it's not of that type.